# How do I use Ruby for shell scripting?

Tags: ruby, shell, scripting

I have some simple shell scripting tasks that I want to do

For example: Selecting a file in the working directory from a list of the files matching some regular expression.

I know that I can do this sort of thing using standard bash and grep but I would be nice to be able to hack quick scripts that will work in windows and linux without me having to memorize a heap of command line programs and flags etc.

I tried to get this going but ended up getting confused about where I should be getting information such as a reference to the current directory

So the question is what parts of the Ruby libraries do I need to know to write ruby shell scripts?

Comment: Probably not a good answer, but Practical Ruby for System Administration is a great reference. http://www.amazon.com/Practical-System-Administration-Experts-Source/dp/1590598210/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1346355414&sr=1-1&keywords=ruby+for+system+administration

Answer (score 152, accepted):

By default, you already have access to [Dir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html) and [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html), which are pretty useful by themselves.

```
Dir['*.rb'] #basic globs
Dir['**/*.rb'] #** == any depth of directory, including current dir.
#=> array of relative names

File.expand_path('~/file.txt') #=> "/User/mat/file.txt"
File.dirname('dir/file.txt') #=> 'dir'
File.basename('dir/file.txt') #=> 'file.txt'
File.join('a', 'bunch', 'of', 'strings') #=> 'a/bunch/of/strings'

__FILE__ #=> the name of the current file
```

Also useful from the stdlib is [FileUtils](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/index.html)

```
require 'fileutils' #I know, no underscore is not ruby-like
include FileUtils
# Gives you access (without prepending by 'FileUtils.') to
cd(dir, options)
cd(dir, options) {|dir| .... }
pwd()
mkdir(dir, options)
mkdir(list, options)
mkdir_p(dir, options)
mkdir_p(list, options)
rmdir(dir, options)
rmdir(list, options)
ln(old, new, options)
ln(list, destdir, options)
ln_s(old, new, options)
ln_s(list, destdir, options)
ln_sf(src, dest, options)
cp(src, dest, options)
cp(list, dir, options)
cp_r(src, dest, options)
cp_r(list, dir, options)
mv(src, dest, options)
mv(list, dir, options)
rm(list, options)
rm_r(list, options)
rm_rf(list, options)
install(src, dest, mode = <src's>, options)
chmod(mode, list, options)
chmod_R(mode, list, options)
chown(user, group, list, options)
chown_R(user, group, list, options)
touch(list, options)
```

Which is pretty nice

Answer (score 116):

As the others have said already, your first line should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

And you also have to make it executable: (in the shell)

```
chmod +x test.rb
```

Then follows the ruby code. If you open a file

```
File.open("file", "r") do |io|
    # do something with io
end
```

the file is opened in the current directory you'd get with `pwd` in the shell.

The path to your script is also simple to get. With `$0` you get the first argument of the shell, which is the relative path to your script. The absolute path can be determined like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'pathname'
p Pathname.new($0).realpath()
```

For file system operations I almost always use Pathname. This is a wrapper for many of the other file system related classes. Also useful: Dir, File...

Answer (score 68):

Here's something important that's missing from the other answers: the command-line parameters are exposed to your Ruby shell script through the ARGV (global) array.

So, if you had a script called my_shell_script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "I was passed: "
ARGV.each do |value|
  puts value
end
```

...make it executable (as others have mentioned):

```
chmod u+x my_shell_script
```

And call it like so:

```
> ./my_shell_script one two three four five
```

You'd get this:

```
I was passed: 
one
two
three
four
five
```

The arguments work nicely with filename expansion:

```
./my_shell_script *

I was passed: 
a_file_in_the_current_directory
another_file    
my_shell_script
the_last_file
```

Most of this only works on UNIX (Linux, Mac OS X), but you can do similar (though less convenient) things in Windows.

Answer (score 32):

There's a lot of good advice here, so I wanted to add a tiny bit more.

1. Backticks (or back-ticks) let you do some scripting stuff a lot easier. Consider

   ```
   puts `find . | grep -i lib`
   ```
2. If you run into problems with getting the output of backticks, the stuff is going to standard err instead of standard out. [Use this advice](http://www.weheartcode.com/2007/09/14/capturing-stderr-with-ruby-backticks/comment-page-1/#comment-30518)

   ```
   out = `git status 2>&1`
   ```
3. Backticks do string interpolation:

   ```
   blah = 'lib'
   `touch #{blah}`
   ```
4. [You can pipe inside Ruby, too](http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-pipe-in-ruby.html). It's a link to my blog, but it links back here so it's okay :) There are probably more advanced things out there on this topic.
5. As other people noted, if you want to get serious there is Rush: not just as a shell replacement (which is a bit too zany for me) but also [as a library for your use in shell scripts and programs.](http://rush.heroku.com/handbook/library)

---

On Mac, Use Applescript inside Ruby for more power. Here's my `shell_here` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
`env | pbcopy` 
cmd =  %Q@tell app "Terminal" to do script "$(paste_env)"@
puts cmd

`osascript -e "${cmd}"`
```

Comment: I just had to indent the code 4 more spaces for them to be formatted.  I also put the backticks back, but I don't know Ruby very well at all, so you'll want to check to make sure it's what you intended.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard, yeah, that was the 'trick' I was needing: the double indents. THANKS FOR THE HELP.

Comment: I think Rush is dead: http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-shell/browse_thread/thread/1f856f6960165309#

Answer (score 21):

Go get yourself a copy of [Everyday Scripting with Ruby](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bmsft/everyday-scripting-with-ruby).  It has plenty of useful tips on how to do the types of things your are wanting to do.

Comment: Good book, I'm reading it right now: it feels like a zen code journey. And if you don't know TDD, you'll learn TDD's basics allong the way.

Comment: I think the book have some good information but to much overhead for experienced programmers.

Answer (score 12):

let's say you write your `script.rb` script. put:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

as the first line and do a `chmod +x script.rb`

Answer (score 12):

This might also be helpful: http://rush.heroku.com/

I haven't used it much, but looks pretty cool

From the site:

> rush is a replacement for the unix shell (bash, zsh, etc) which uses pure Ruby syntax. Grep through files, find and kill processes, copy files - everything you do in the shell, now in Ruby

Comment: Rush: no. Why? http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-shell/browse_thread/thread/75c8cea757d2f680# It's great but there's no one at the wheel.

Answer (score 7):

When you want to write more complex ruby scripts, these tools may help:

For example:

- [thor](http://github.com/wycats/thor)(a scripting framework)
- [gli](http://davetron5000.github.com/gli/)(git like interface)
- [methadone](https://github.com/davetron5000/methadone)(for creating simple tools)

They give you a quick start to write your own scripts, especially 'command line app'.

Answer (score 6):

The above answer are interesting and very helpful when using Ruby as shell script. For me, I does not use Ruby as my daily language and I prefer to use ruby as flow control only and still use bash to do the tasks.

Some helper function can be used for testing execution result

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
module ShellHelper
  def test(command)
    `#{command} 2> /dev/null`
    $?.success?
  end

  def execute(command, raise_on_error = true)
    result = `#{command}`
    raise "execute command failed\n" if (not $?.success?) and raise_on_error
    return $?.success?
  end

  def print_exit(message)
    print "#{message}\n"
    exit
  end

  module_function :execute, :print_exit, :test
end
```

With helper, the ruby script could be bash alike:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require './shell_helper'
include ShellHelper

print_exit "config already exists" if test "ls config"

things.each do |thing|
  next if not test "ls #{thing}/config"
  execute "cp -fr #{thing}/config_template config/#{thing}"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

"How do I write ruby" is a little beyond the scope of SO.

But to turn these ruby scripts into executable scripts, put this as the first line of your ruby script:

```
#!/path/to/ruby
```

Then make the file executable:

```
chmod a+x myscript.rb
```

and away you go.

Answer (score 4):

Place this at the beginning of your script.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Then mark it as executable:

```
chmod +x script.rb
```

Answer (score 3):

In ruby, the constant `__FILE__` will always give you the path of the script you're running.

On Linux, `/usr/bin/env` is your friend:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
# Extension of this script does not matter as long
# as it is executable (chmod +x)
puts File.expand_path(__FILE__)
```

On Windows it depends whether or not .rb files are associated with ruby.
If they are:

```
# This script filename must end with .rb
puts File.expand_path(__FILE__)
```

If they are not, you have to explicitly invoke ruby on them, I use a intermediate .cmd file:

my_script.cmd:

```
@ruby %~dp0\my_script.rb
```

my_script.rb:

```
puts File.expand_path(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by [webmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6349/webmat) is perfect. I just want to point you to a addition. If you have to deal a lot with command line parameters for your scripts, you should use [optparse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html). It is simple and helps you tremendously.