# metasploit ruby script to execute shell commands

Tags: ruby, shell

I am trying to make a metasploit script to execute a shell command. 
The commands that I want to be execute in metasploit is the following

```
shell
cd /data/data/com.metasploit.stage/files
sh and.sh
exit
```

I'm not familiar with ruby. Can anybody tell me how I can make it to work 
I try to use `exec('shell')` for the first command but it doesn't work.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/166347/2681997. You can run any shell command in ruby using Backticks (or back-ticks).

Comment: I will try. Thank you